# GetDirectories. Retrieve directories not containing a word in its name

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 string[] fileNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation);
        foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
        {

            item = new ListItem();
            item.Value = item.Text = "Add " + fileName.Substring(startSize);
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
            CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(item);
            CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(item);
```

This is returning back the directories, however there are some directories contain the term Cobol in the folders name. Can I return the other folders and exclude those containing that word in the folder name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation).Where(x=>!x.Contains("Cobol")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, getting an error here. Is this because I have named the folder above? New to this right now.


Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)


Above code :
 ListItem item;
            string folderLocation = @"\\serv5007i\TeamCityDeploy\Trunk Production Build\Current\bin\Runtime";
            int startSize = folderLocation.Length+1;

Comment: @conye9980 You are missing a `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

Question answered by tym32167 & InBetween

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetDirectories(folderLocation).Where(x=>!x.Contains("Cobol")).ToArray();
    foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
    {

        item = new ListItem();
        item.Value = item.Text = "Add " + fileName.Substring(startSize);
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
        CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(item);
        CheckBoxList3.Items.Add(item);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `ToArray`.  Just `foreach` over the resulting `IEnumerable<string>` instead.

Comment: Sorry to add on, if I want it to exlude different terms? !x.Contains("Cobol", "HTML))
Would this be correct?

Comment: Then you'd want a collection of the terms and use `All`, like this `x => new[]{"Cobol", "HTML"}.All(y => !x.Contains(y))`

Comment: I'm a little confused on that, could you explain it further?